# Android: Tab view fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I'm trying to implement a swipe tab views like this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/.
But when I try to implement getItems method in the Adapter, it doesn't accept my custom Fragment.
Here's the code:
*MyActivity.java*

```
package com.bob.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private String[] tabs = { getString(R.string.tab_home), getString(R.string.tab_city), getString(R.string.tab_name),getString(R.string.tab_favorites) };
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private String[] Drawer_menu_item;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener((android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener) this));
            Drawer_menu_item= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_item);
            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

            // Set the adapter for the list view
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.drawer, Drawer_menu_item));
            /* Set the list's click listener
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());*/
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {

            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    /* Home fragment
                    return new Home_fragment();
                case 1:
                    /* City fragment
                    return new City_fragment();
                case 2:
                    /* Name fragment
                    return new Name_fragment();
                case 3:
                    /* Favourites fragment
                    return new Fav_fragment();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // get item count - equal to number of tabs
            return tabs.length;
        }

    }
}
```

*Name_fragment.java*

```
package com.bob.sluurpy.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by boob on 11/09/15.
 */
public class Name_fragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please import this  `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` in place of `import android.app.Fragment;` in `Name_fragment` this may solve your issue!

Comment: @Bobb1 if this answer helped, please accept answer!